# Metadata of Getting number of rows in Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, metadata

How come is it not possible to return number of rows in a View using sys.views in the below query while using sys.table you can

```
SELECT t.NAME AS table_name,
       s.name AS owner,
       p.[Rows] as NUM_ROWS,
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN   
     sys.indexes i 
     ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id INNER JOIN
     sys.partitions p
     ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id inner join
     sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND 
      i.index_id <= 1 /* AND
            s.name in ('Schemaname1','Schemaname2') */
GROUP BY t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name,s.name, p.[Rows]
ORDER BY object_name(i.object_id) ;
```

Comment: Views simply store code.  Unless materialized, they have no concept of how many rows are in the view.

Comment: WITH SCHEMABINDING

Comment: @jarlh sql dbms

Comment: Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh yes MS SQL Server

Comment: @CheriChoc - SCHEMABINDING merely imposes restrictions on how you reference other objects within the view (and protects the view from those objects from being changed in such a way as to "break" the view). While it's a requirement for a materialized/indexed view, the converse isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

Its a syntax issue you got, an extra comma in the query after NUM_ROWS ?

```
SELECT t.NAME AS table_name,
       s.name AS owner,
       p.[Rows] as NUM_ROWS /*, remove this comma*/
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN   
     sys.indexes i 
     ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id INNER JOIN
     sys.partitions p
     ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id inner join
     sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND 
      i.index_id <= 1 /* AND
            s.name in ('Schemaname1','Schemaname2') */
GROUP BY t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name,s.name, p.[Rows]
ORDER BY object_name(i.object_id) ;
```